# Apply regex to every row of a spark dataframe and save it as a new column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a spark dataframe,

data.show()

```
ID                URL
1             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed
2             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed
3             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed
4             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed
5                 None
```

I want to write a regex operation to it, where I want to parse the URL for a particular scenario. The scenario would be would be to parse out after &q and before next &. I am able to write this in python for a python dataframe as follows,

```
re.sub(r"\s+", " ", re.search(r'/?q=([^&]*)', data['url'][i]).group(1).replace('+', ' ')
```

I want to write the same in pyspark.

If a write something like,

```
 re.sub(r"\s+", " ", re.search(r'/?q=([^&]*)', data.select(data.url.alias("url")).collect()).group(1).replace('+', ' '))
```

or

```
re.sub(r"\s+", " ", re.search(r'/?q=([^&]*)', data.select(data['url']).collect()).group(1).replace('+', ' '))
```

I am getting the following error,

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

One option is that to convert the data to pandas using,

`data.toPandas()` and then do the operations. But my data is huge and converting it to pandas makes it slow. Is there a way I can write this directly to a new column in spark dataframe where I can have like,

```
ID                URL                                                                           word
1             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed       To Be Parsed out   
2             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed       To Be Parsed out 
3             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed       To Be Parsed out 
4             https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed       To Be Parsed out 
5             None                                                                             None
```

How can we do this to add it as a new table in pyspark dataframe? which applies to every row of the dataframe?

Comment: Look into using a udf along with `withColumn` or transforming your your dataframe to a rdd and using `map`

Comment: @David I am new to pyspark. Just getting to know these. If you dont mind, can I ask you for helping to use map function ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @David in the comment, you could use `udf` and `withColumn`:

**Scala code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val getWord: (String => String) = (url: String) => {
  if (url != null) {
    """/?q=([^&]*)""".r
      .findFirstIn(url)
      .get
      .replaceAll("q=", "")
      .replaceAll("\\+", " ")
  }
  else
    null
}
val udfGetWord = udf(getWord)
df.withColumn("word", udfGetWord($"url")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pyspark Code:**

```
#Create dataframe with sample data

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed'),(2,'https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed'),(3,'https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed'),(4,'https://www.sitename.com/&q=To+Be+Parsed+out&oq=Dont+Need+to+be+parsed'),(5,'None')],['id','url'])
```

Use `substr` to cut desired string using location index and `instr` to identify location of search pattern.

`regexp_replace` used to replace '+' sign with space.

```
df.selectExpr("id",
              "url",
              "regexp_replace(substr(url,instr(url,'&q')+3, instr(url,'&oq') - instr(url,'&q') - 3 ),'\\\+',' ') AS word")\
.show()

#+---+--------------------+----------------+
#| id|                 url|            word|
#+---+--------------------+----------------+
#|  1|https://www.siten...|To Be Parsed out|
#|  2|https://www.siten...|To Be Parsed out|
#|  3|https://www.siten...|To Be Parsed out|
#|  4|https://www.siten...|To Be Parsed out|
#|  5|                None|                |
#+---+--------------------+----------------+
```

If search pattern does not exists in search string blank would be returned. This can be handles using `case` statement.